# An interpolation estimate involving fractional derivatives

Tags: harmonic-analysis, interpolation-spaces

I have come across various instances of interpolation estimates of the following type:

$ \| f \|_{L^r(\mathbb{R^n})} \lesssim \| |\nabla|^{-s_1} f \|_{L^{r_1}(\mathbb{R^n})}^\theta \| |\nabla|^{s_2} f \|_{L^{r_2}(\mathbb{R^n})}^{1-\theta}$,

where

$\tfrac{1}{r} = \tfrac{\theta}{r_1}+\tfrac{1-\theta}{r_2}$

and $s_1,s_2>0$ satisfy

$-s_1\theta + s_2(1-\theta) =0$.

Here $|\nabla|^s$ are the usual fractional derivative operators defined via the Fourier transform. I am not sure what restrictions on the exponents are needed beyond $1\leq r,r_1,r_2\leq \infty$ (perhaps excluding the endpoints).

I was hoping that someone could help me understand what type of interpolation is being used here and precisely how it is being applied.

In fact, I believe that one can prove this estimate directly for $1<r,r_1,r_2<\infty$ via the square function estimate and Hölder's inequality (first in the sums and then in the integrals), using

$|P_N f|^2 = ( N^{-2s_1}|P_Nf|^2)^\theta (N^{2s_2}|P_N f|^2)^{1-\theta}$

for an individual Littlewood-Paley piece.

But, clearly the estimate should follow from some appropriate interpolation, and I would be very grateful to understand exactly what type of interpolation is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation.

If I understand you correctly, then your $|| |\nabla|^{-s_1}||_{L^{r_1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is just the norm of the Bessel potential space $H^{-s_1}_{r_1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For the complex interpolation method we have (using your notation)

$(H^{s_2}_{r_2}(\mathbb{R}^n), H^{-s_1}_{r_1}(\mathbb{R}^n))_{[\theta]}=H^0_r(\mathbb{R}^n)$

for $0<\theta<1$ and $1<r_1,r_2<\infty$.

Is it this kind of result you were looking for?

Comment: Yes --- this would be the kind of answer I am looking for.  Does the fact that $L^r$ is given by this interpolation space actually imply that the estimate written in the original question holds?

Comment: Yes, see for example these [lecture notes](http://prmat.math.unipr.it/~lunardi/LectureNotes/SNS1999.pdf) of A. Lunardi, Corollary 2.1.8 on page 48.